How to fix the broken pressure srtength function in 2D projects
I downloaded blender, strength simply did not work in 2D projects, although I changed the intensity and used pressure strength. And I used exactly those brushes with which pressure strength was supposed to function, for example, pencil and pencil soft. On advice from the Internet I changed the tablet API to Windows Ink, Automatic and Wintab, but nothing worked (I did not connect a graphics tablet to the computer). Then, following another advice, I deleted the blender downloaded from Steam and installed it from the official website. I opened the 2D project again, but this function still did not work there. Apart from this problem, everything in the blender works fine. I just recently started using a blender, maybe I don’t understand something, but I hope you can help me solve the problem.

Don't understand the bit about "I did not connect a graphics tablet to the computer"! The pressure strength works by the pressure you apply to your tablet pen so if you don't have one and are relying on a mouse to draw  it isn't going to work!

I probably mistyped, I meant that I connected the graphics tablet to the computer, I draw with a pen on the tablet. But I don't understand what is meant by "Don't understand the bit about I did not connect a graphics tablet to the computer", maybe you didn't understand me because of a typo. Anyway, I have a tablet pen, but for some reason this function does not work for me.

It probably depends on the make of tablet. See if it has a settings application with it. My Wacom tablet worked out of the box for me without changing any settings. You could also search online for "Using Blender with a <your make/model> tablet".
